# How to enter 24:00 in a html5 time input?

Tags: html, forms

I use a html5 time input:

```
<input type="time" />
```

My application takes a time interval for working hours, or availibility. This works fine for 9-17 or similar. But the problem arises when I want to be able to enter 00:00 - 24:00, that means the entire day. There is no way to enter 24:00.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Basically, the entire day end at 23:59:59... 24:00 and 00:00 are the same, just different days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a checkbox instead for selecting the entire day. Or you can use text input and validate it with js. But the problem is that 24.00 is not a valid date.

Comment: "Entire day" checkbox is how I've always done and seen it done too. I'd also assert it's what users expect to find nowadays.